# Sum of fraction series

Tags: fractions

I have been trying to solve this question but I am not sure how to, and would appreciate some help. Thanks.

> Simplify: 
>   $$\frac{1}{4} +\frac{1}{4^2} +\frac{4^2}{4^3} +\frac{4^2}{4^4} +\frac{4^4}{4^5} +\frac{4^4}{4^6} +\ldots +\frac{4^{102}}{4^{103}} +\frac{4^{102}}{4^{104}}.$$

Comment: Jimmy: what are the first two terms, and the next two and so on? Can you sum a geometric series?

Comment: You're just repeatedly adding $\frac{1}{4}$ and $\frac{1}{16}$...